# Match data in two columns and add match to the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe : 
First dataframe

> ```
>           Column1     Column2    Column3          
>        0  A1          B1         C1
>        1  A2          B2         C2
>        2  A3          B3         C3
>        2  A4          B4         C4
> ```

Second dataframe

> ```
>           Column1     Column2         
>        0  A1          S1         
>        1  B3          S2         
>        2  A3          S3        
>        3  B5          S4  
>        4  A5          S5
> ```

I want to join the two tables, on value in Column1, COlumn2 in dataframe 1 with Column1 in dataframe 2

> ```
> Whatever A* value from DF2 matches with Column1 values in DF1, the corresponding Column2 value goes into Column 4 in output.
> Whatever D* value from DF2 matches with Column1 values in DF1, the corresponding Column2 value goes into Column 5 in output.
> ```

The output should be something like this:

> ```
>           Column1     Column2    Column3   Column4     Column5      
>        0  A1          B1         C1        S1
>        1  A2          B2         C2                    
>        2  A3          B3         C3        S3            S2
>        2  A4          B4         C4
> ```

A1 matched, hence S1 went to column4
B3 matched, hence S2 went  to column5
A3 matched, hence S3 went to column4
B5 didn't match hence wan't displayed at all
A5 didn't match hence wasn't displayed at all.

The dirty way I have done this is separate A* and B* values into two separate dataframes and merge them using outer join. But I am looking for a way to be able to this without creating two separate datasets for df2 data.

Comment: Does df1 and df2 the same length?

Comment: @Joe: From the given example, no!

Comment: @misguided: It is really not clear, what's the logic behind the result creation. E.g. why you add "SampleE" values in the result dataframe after you compare data in "SampleD" with data from "SampleB". Also, why in the result dataframe you have rows "Sample" and "SampleE_1"? Also, where do you get entries `S1` and `T1` from, they do not appear in the dataframes `df1` and `df2`

Comment: @SimonFink apologies those were typos(T1,S1). I have updated the question. I want to compare SampleB and D(values starting with B*) and add corresponding values of Sample D and E to the result dataset. Similarly compare SampleA and D (values staring with A*) and add corresponding values of Sample D and E to the result dataset.

Comment: Can you please describe the generation of "SampleD", "SampleD_1", "SampleE" and "SampleE_1" in more detail? Hard to guess what you are trying. Especially, why certain entries are in that row, while others are not. Why is `A1` in "SampleD" and `A3` and `A7` in "SampleD_1?

Comment: Apologies updated it again. You are right A1,A3,A7 should be in SampleD_1 and S1,S3,S5 should be in SampleE_1.

Comment: Still it is not clear where those values `S1`, `S2`, etc. come from and how they are split up between "SampleE" and "SampleE_1". Not wasting more energy on this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code do the job on your example:

```py
result_df = (
    df1.merge(
        df2.rename({'Column2': 'Column4'}, axis='columns'), how='left', on=['Column1']
    )
    .merge(
        df2.rename({'Column2': 'Column5'}, axis='columns'),
        how='left',
        left_on=['Column2'],
        right_on=['Column1'],
    )
    .drop(['Column1_y'], axis='columns')
    .rename({'Column1_x': 'Column1'}, axis='columns')
)
```

I am not really happy about the last two commands `drop` and `rename` but I can't avoid this duplication of columns in the second merge.

*Edit*: forgot the `axis` argument in the last `rename` function.

Comment: the last rename doesn't work with the code above. I have used your earlier code to modify it slightly `.rename({'Column1_x': 'Column1'}, axis='columns')` . I am assuming it was typo that you missed the details out.

Answer (score 0):

Using the the answer above, I have come up with another way to implement this:

```
result_df1 = (df1.merge(
    df2[df2['Column1'].str.contains(r'A')]
    .rename({'Column2': 'Column4'},axis='columns'),
    how='outer',
    on=['Column1']
    )
    .merge(
    df2[df2['Column1'].str.contains(r'B')]
    .rename({'Column2': 'Column5','Column1': 'Column2'},axis='columns'),
    how='outer',
    on=['Column2']
    )
    .replace(np.nan, '', regex=True))
```